# How to copy files from one machine to another machine

Tags: shell, unix

I want to copy `/home/cmind012/m.sh` from one system to another system (both system Linux) using shell script.

Command $

```
scp /home/cmind012/m.sh  cmind013:/home/cmind013/tanu
```

getting message

```
ssh: cmind013: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

Comment: does your DNS work? `ping cmind013`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the IP Address/Domain of the remote host.  The format should be user@host:[directory]

You could do the following:

```
scp -r [directory/files] [remote host]:[destination directory]
ex: scp -r /var/www/html/* root@192.168.1.0:/var/www/html/
```

Comment: scp -R /home/cmind012/* root@172.22.192.105:/home/cmind013/

scp: illegal option -- R

usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]

           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2

Comment: @Ban sorry my bad it should be a small "r"

Comment: password: ........ then i am getting message 
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: @Ban you replace root (if you don't have root access to the remote host) to your username

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cmind013 is not being resolved, I would try using first

```
nslookup cming013
```

and see what why donesn't it resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
scp /home/cmind012/m.sh denil@172.22.192.105:/home/denil/
```